# fast way to look in set of real numbers

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, c#-4.0, search

I am working in C# 4.0 and I have the following problem:

given a finite set S of real numbers and a parameter k (NOT NECESSARILY IN THE SET), find **the smallest number in S greater than or equal to k**.

Obviously, I could use a balanced binary tree to do so. However, there is no implementation of such data structure in C# that could help me. What are the options of algorithms and possible implementations in C#?

Edit:

since most of people are more interested in criticizing than really helping, I will explain more:

it is for an algorithm that divides a real function in millions of pieces (or bins, like an histogram), and I need to find the piece that contains k in and efficient way to apply some computation in it. The pieces are real intervals of the form [a; b) and do not overlap.

The method I am designing needs to take the piece, given k, and is performance critical since it should be called thousands of times per second. Therefore, an O(n) search is unacceptable.

The time wasted on building the data structure of S is not important and not critical, since the set will be built only once and will never change (it is an immutable set).

I know I could use a red black tree, which has O(log n) search complexity. However, I'd like to investigate other algorithm options (and possibly with existing implementations in C#).

Comment: So is this a homework or interview question?

Comment: @RQDQ what is the reason that you ask?

Comment: "there is no implementation of such data structure in C# that could help me" - then implement one (or find someone else's implementation)!

Comment: If it's not homework I would suggest the "fastest" method is probably not necessary.  Searching a sorted list may be "fast enough".

Comment: Implement your own comparer: http://stefanoricciardi.com/2010/03/02/comparing-floating-point-numbers/

Comment: @Артём Царионов - because my answer would vary depending on whether this is learning exercise or a real world scenario.

Comment: This is not homework nor interview and it is not a trivial question. This is a real world scenario where I have a set with millions of elements and I should find the smallest element in the set grater than k.

Comment: @RQDQ how come? i thought we are just supposed to try our best to answer the question if we know the answer

Comment: "Set of real numbers"? It sounds more like math than C#. The described number may not exist, for example if `S = { 1/n | n∈N }` and `k = 0`. Another example would be if all numbers in `S` were strictly negative, and `k = 0`.

Comment: we are loosing focus. This is an algorithm problem. I have never said that k must exist in the set and, since it is a question on a computer science forum, it is OBVIOUS that I am dealing with FINITE sets. I recommend you reading the question all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be (`O(N)`) :

```
double k = 3.5;
List<double> S = new List<double>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 };

var min = S.Where(f => f >= k).Min(); //4
```

---

if your list is already sorted then the cost is `O(LogN)`

```
List<double> S = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var index = S.BinarySearch(k);
var min = index > 0 ? S[index] : S[~index];
```

Comment: @DStanley Sort is O(N*LogN) operation, but the cost of above code is O(N). (Just *one pass* over the list)

Comment: A balanced binary tree is O(log n).

Comment: @user38397 But you have the cost of forming a balanced tree. I will update the answer.

Comment: I updated the question. The cost of building the data structure is not important and not critical.

Comment: @user38397 Then sort your set once and use a binarysearch as in my 2nd example (it's `O(LogN)`).

Comment: Ok, good answer. I was not aware of BinarySearch method in .net List<T>. However, there is another post here talking about a O(1) algorithm for this. I will try to find about it and, if not, you will be marked as answer. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is trivial to solve in O(n) time. Loop over all elements, keep track of the smallest element found so far fulfilling the criteria (not being smaller than k).

If repeated with different k: binary search a sorted array O(log n)

If the maximum element size is bounded, a bucket sort like architecture would give O(1) time.

Comment: Why a bucket sort architecture is O(1)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use [SCG.SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx), which is, under the covers, a red-black tree.

You could use SCG.List or an array, sort it and use its [BinarySearch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) method.

You could use the [C5 Collections Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) as well.

If this is homework, you could roll your own implementation (likely what the professor wants, I'd imagine). Lots o'options out there.

Answer (score 0):

Not the "fastest" but a `SortedList` may be "fast enough":

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double FindSmallestGreaterThan(this SortedList<double,double> list, double value)
    {
       foreach(double d in list.Keys)
       {
           if(d > value) return d;
       }
       throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("No values in the list greater than " + value.ToString());
    }
}
```

usage would be:

```
SortedList<double,double> list = new SortedList<double,double>();
list.Add(0.5, 0.5);
list.Add(1.9, 1.9);

double d = list.FindSmallestGreaterThan(1.0);
```

Comment: This code is O(n), since I must iterate through the entire list. I don't want to discuss code, but algorithms and alternatives in c#.